# Cloud Database access security

Tags: database, cloud, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a project where I have to store data from a Raspberry (which will have a mobile broadband connection and it will be on a public place) to a PostgreSQL Database in the cloud (Don't know if PostgreSQL is the best option). Also I have to access these data from a Web Application built on PHP, it will be available for everyone.

I'm stuck thinking about all the security issues, I can't even figure out what problems I'll be facing due to I'm relatively new working on this.

Can you suggest me some articles or give me some tips about the things that I have to focus my attention?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a DBMS that's designed to be accessed directly via the public Internet, e.g. MongoDB.  Such systems give you fine-grained control over who has access to each part of your database, and they tend to have APIs that are easier to use from web and mobile apps.

PostgreSQL is great, too, but it's usually deployed behind some kind of server-side middleware that handles application-specific authentication and authorization.

Another option is a DBaaS like Firebase or Backendless, both of which have free tiers.  They're easier to set up and administer than most self-hosted solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to consider -

1. Client-side encryption, where an encryption key is used on the client to encrypt certain data attributes before sending it to the cloud
2. On the wire encryption using TLS and CA-signed certificates
3. Server-side encryption and encryption at rest